# Can I use SignalR for developing instant messing client?

Tags: signalr

I want to develop a instant messaging client like whatsapp for phone platform (Android/WP/iOS). I came across SignalR and when I saw tutorials, it looks SignalR can be used. But I'm not an expert in it. So, can I use SignalR for developing instant messing client?

If yes, what are the pros/cons of using SignalR, specifically in terms of reliability of sending/receiving message and scalability (more than 50k users)?